# Customizing the popup menu of a DropdownButton

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter, flutter-layout, dropdownbutton

How can you set the background color of the `DropdownButton` menu.  I can customize the `Text()` items that appear but they appear within a container which I would like to change the color for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dropdownColor` setting handles this:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  dropdownColor: Colors.blue,

 // ...
}
```

[image]

.. found it thanks to options offered by autocomplete

Comment: How use a image instead of just color?

Comment: [Google search "flutter dropdownbutton background image"](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=flutter+dropdownbutton+background+image&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Obviously I googled before asking, and I didn't find.

Comment: It would be obvious if you wrote a new post explaining what you have found so far and what you have tried yourself.  Since you asked here in a comment with just a sentence and nothing else to explain & understand **what specifically** you are trying to accomplish, no it was not at all obvious if you searched.  I was trying to be polite and not leave your question completely unanswered. MCVE: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).   Best with your iniatitives

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```dart
          DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: model.id,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: width,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green, // 
                child: Text(
                  model.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        )
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any effect and doesn't provide how to get the value of the SizedBox width.  Container wraps tightly around Text and does not color the "parent" of the DropDownMenuItem

Answer (score 0):

```
int _value = 0;

Widget _buildDropdown() {
  return DropdownButton(
    value: _value,
    items: [
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue, // you need this
          child: Text("Zero"),
          width: 100,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green, // you need this
          child: Text("One"),
          width: 100,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _value = value),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CopsOnRoad.  This is what I tried but the Container wraps tightly around it's children so the color does not extend to the edges of the Popup Menu.

Comment: @AlanKley Yes, you are right, there is some padding there and it will be there unless you play with the system files.